# adobe XD can't create document (error code: 3623)

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

When I try to create a adobe XD document this message Appear to me 
adobe XD can't create document (error code: 3623)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There may be a version issue here.
Please update your XD Version

If this does not work, try these steps:

1. Convert XD file to .psd file in Photopia Website
2. Open .psd file with XD and save as XD file